# Layering issue with Adobe Edge on iPad only

Tags: javascript, ios, css, ipad, adobe-edge

I have a fairly simple button symbol that I'm adding dynamically to the stage.  The button has a background layer and a text layer.  Everything works fine in the standard browsers but on iPad the background layer unexpectedly covers the text (as if on a higher z-index though no value shows in the DOM and attempts to override the z-index via css do nothing).  Further more this issue only seems to trigger when I go to a label in the button such as;

```
button.stop("Idle");
```

Has anyone else had random layering issue on iPad that may relate to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who may be searching;  Apparently vector shapes do not appear smoothly and consistently in all webkit browsers (the primary culprit mentioned was Android native browser).  As an artificial optimization you can apply a 3D transform (but without actually scaling or rotating) in order to improve the vector rendering.  In Adobe Edge this is done by applying a 'translateZ" transform to all of the elements on the stage. However this also causes random issues with any item I'm trying to layer with "z-index".

The solution is to clear out this transform on the problematic elements (or edit the edge classes to removed them globally) like so;

```
buttonFrameSym.$("select_arrow").css("-webkit-transform", "none");
```